# TeX Stack Exchange Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place…

If you're a moderator on the main site, would you be interested in having your own TeX Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup: (I copied the site description text from the [/about page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/about). Feel free to make suggestions where you see fit. I had to shorten the front side's description is bit due to spacing).

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: tex.stackexchange.com moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: Shouldn't it say "I am a Community Moderator on TeX Stack Exchange", i.e. 'e' and not 'E' in 'TeX'.

Comment: @N.N. you're right, I'll correct that when printing.

Answer (score 9):

That's a nice idea.

I would like to see the subtle TeX design (math, chemistry, Tengwar) also behind the {TeX} logo on the card.

Further, it would be great if those cards look somehow official, because they originate from the StackExchange company. Having a modarator.name@stackexchange.com email address instead of private/somewhere mail addresses would also support the idea of representing the TeX.StackExchange community.

Answer (score 6):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

They look nice! I really like to have some. I can send my details by PM.